# Why is there prompt asking for a MySQL server password when I did not even set one?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just installed MySQL just now so I shouldn't have been able to place a password beforehand.

This appears when I try to test the connection:
[image: MySQL Password Prompt]

Then if I leave it blank, it errors. 
[image: Error]

I also tried 'root' as password and 'admin' just to try a few and it still errors. I try to type mysql -u root -p in MySQL shell but it keeps saying i'm not connected. I'm lost.

Comment: normally when you install it, it asks you to define the root password. Did this not happen? What O/S did you install on?

Comment: Nope didn't touch it. Windows 7

Comment: Is there any way to see the password?

Comment: No. Otherwise what would be the point of having a password? :-)

Comment: Are you _sure_ the install process didn't ask you to set a root password? I think your best bet at this point is probably to un-install, then try and re-install and see what happens. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation.html is the reference guide to installation on windows.

Comment: Yeah I believe so. Thanks

Comment: A page within that, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-installer-workflow.html says "Assigning a root password is required and you will be asked for it when performing other MySQL Installer operations." So watch out for that step.

Comment: Yeah i'm guessing I might have typed in a 'password' and not realized it

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know until after it connects whether there is a password or not. That's because it needs the password to connect. So it always asks for one.

I think the problem you have is that there is a subtle difference between no password and a blank password and because you're not entering one, the connection is being made with no password when perhaps you've set a blank one.

Perhaps try to find the MySQL CLI client for Windows and look at the `--password` option.